# Call to stored procedure returning 1 of 30 characters

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am programmatically calling a SQL Server stored procedure which should return 30 random characters. Instead, it is only returning 1 char. What am I missing?

The stored procedure is working as it should when I execute it in SQL Server, but in the C#, its not working correctly.

```
var messageId = "";

try
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GenerateMessageId", conn))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@msgid", messageId);
            command.Parameters[0].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            messageId = (string)command.Parameters[0].Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GenerateMessageId]
    @msgid varchar(30) OUT
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    EXEC dbo.GenerateRandomString 1, 1, 1, null, 30, @msgid OUT
END
```

Comment: show the stored procedure.

Comment: Try to avoid of not-so-good method `AddWithValue` which is trying to guess parameter type and instead use `Add` with explicit declaration of parameter type.

Comment: Have you verified that your procedure **actually** returns 30 characters when run in SSMS?

Comment: Yes, I mentioned above that I executed the sproc in SQL Server to the desired effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to add:

```
command.Parameters[0].Size = 30;
```

or

```
command.Parameters.Add("@msgid", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

or use explicit declaration:

```
 SqlParameter msgid= new SqlParameter {
    ParameterName = "@msgid",
    IsNullable    = true,
    Direction     = ParameterDirection.Output,
    DbType        = DbType.String,
    Size          = 30,
    Value         = messageId,
    } ;
  command.Parameters.Add(msgid);
```

Comment: The runtime sets the parameter size to zero as the string is empty, which is fine for an input parameter, not so good for an output parameter!